# Error restriccion de columnas en tablas POSTGRESQL SQL state: 42830

Tags: postgresql

Tengo un problema al tratar de crear esta BD, siempre me salta el mismo error

> ERROR:  no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas
>   en la tabla referida «pbombonas»

Creo que el error esta al final del script, ya que es la unica que no se ejecuto correctamente pero no he logrado encontrar que es lo que podria estar mal

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.pestado_peid_seq_1;

CREATE TABLE public.pestado (
                peid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.pestado_peid_seq_1'),
                pestatus VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT pestado_pk PRIMARY KEY (peid)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.pestado_peid_seq_1 OWNED BY public.pestado.peid;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.proles_prid_seq_1_1;

CREATE TABLE public.proles (
                prid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.proles_prid_seq_1_1'),
                prol VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT proles_pk PRIMARY KEY (prid)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.proles_prid_seq_1_1 OWNED BY public.proles.prid;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.pdepartamento_piddepa_seq_2;

CREATE TABLE public.pdepartamento (
                piddepa INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.pdepartamento_piddepa_seq_2'),
                pdepa VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT pdepartamento_pk PRIMARY KEY (piddepa)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.pdepartamento_piddepa_seq_2 OWNED BY public.pdepartamento.piddepa;

CREATE TABLE public.pcargos (
                pidca INTEGER NOT NULL,
                piddepa INTEGER NOT NULL,
                ptitulo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT pcargos_pk PRIMARY KEY (pidca, piddepa)
);




CREATE SEQUENCE public.pempleados_pidemple_seq_1_1_1;

CREATE TABLE public.pempleados (
                pidemple INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.pempleados_pidemple_seq_1_1_1'),
                pidca INTEGER NOT NULL,
                piddepa INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pnombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                papellido VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                pcedula NUMERIC(8) NOT NULL,
                pcorreo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                activo BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                pbloq BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT pempleados_pk PRIMARY KEY (pidemple, pidca, piddepa)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.pempleados_pidemple_seq_1_1_1 OWNED BY public.pempleados.pidemple;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.pprovee_ppid_seq_1;

CREATE TABLE public.pprovee (
                ppid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.pprovee_ppid_seq_1'),
                prif VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                pnombre VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
                pdircc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT pprovee_pk PRIMARY KEY (ppid)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.pprovee_ppid_seq_1 OWNED BY public.pprovee.ppid;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.pboca_pidboca_seq_1;

CREATE TABLE public.pboca (
                pidboca INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.pboca_pidboca_seq_1'),
                pboc VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT pboca_pk PRIMARY KEY (pidboca)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.pboca_pidboca_seq_1 OWNED BY public.pboca.pidboca;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.ptama_pidtama_seq_1;

CREATE TABLE public.ptama (
                pidtama INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.ptama_pidtama_seq_1'),
                ptaman VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT ptama_pk PRIMARY KEY (pidtama)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.ptama_pidtama_seq_1 OWNED BY public.ptama.pidtama;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.pbombonas_pbid_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.pbombonas (
                pbid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.pbombonas_pbid_seq'),
                pserial BIGINT NOT NULL,
                pidboca INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pidtama INTEGER NOT NULL,
                peid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                ppid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                plote VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                pbactiv BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                pfechaing DATE NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT bombonas_pk PRIMARY KEY (pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.pbombonas_pbid_seq OWNED BY public.pbombonas.pbid;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.phistorico_pidhisto_seq_1;

CREATE TABLE public.phistorico (
                pidhisto INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.phistorico_pidhisto_seq_1'),
                pbid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pserial BIGINT NOT NULL,
                pidboca INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pidtama INTEGER NOT NULL,
                peid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                ppid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pfechamodi DATE NOT NULL,
                pobser VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT historic_pk PRIMARY KEY (pidhisto, pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.phistorico_pidhisto_seq_1 OWNED BY public.phistorico.pidhisto;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.usuario_pid_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.usuario (
                pid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.usuario_pid_seq'),
                prid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pidemple INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pidca INTEGER NOT NULL,
                piddepa INTEGER NOT NULL,
                pusuario VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
                pclave VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
                pactivo BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT usuario_pk PRIMARY KEY (pid, prid, pidemple, pidca, piddepa)
);




ALTER SEQUENCE public.usuario_pid_seq OWNED BY public.usuario.pid;

ALTER TABLE public.pbombonas ADD CONSTRAINT pestado_pbombonas_fk
FOREIGN KEY (peid)
REFERENCES public.pestado (peid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.usuario ADD CONSTRAINT proles_usuario_fk
FOREIGN KEY (prid)
REFERENCES public.proles (prid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.pcargos ADD CONSTRAINT pdepartamento_pcargos_fk
FOREIGN KEY (piddepa)
REFERENCES public.pdepartamento (piddepa)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.pempleados ADD CONSTRAINT pcargos_pempleados_fk
FOREIGN KEY (pidca, piddepa)
REFERENCES public.pcargos (pidca, piddepa)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.usuario ADD CONSTRAINT pempleados_usuario_fk
FOREIGN KEY (pidemple, pidca, piddepa)
REFERENCES public.pempleados (pidemple, pidca, piddepa)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.pbombonas ADD CONSTRAINT pprovee_pbombonas_fk
FOREIGN KEY (ppid)
REFERENCES public.pprovee (ppid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.pbombonas ADD CONSTRAINT pboca_pbombonas_fk
FOREIGN KEY (pidboca)
REFERENCES public.pboca (pidboca)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.pbombonas ADD CONSTRAINT ptama_pbombonas_fk
FOREIGN KEY (pidtama)
REFERENCES public.ptama (pidtama)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

*ALTER TABLE public.phistorico ADD CONSTRAINT pbombonas_phistorico_fk
FOREIGN KEY (pbid, pserial, pidtama, peid, ppid)
REFERENCES public.pbombonas (pbid, pserial, pidtama, peid, ppid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;*
```

Comment: Al crear la tabla `pbombonas` has indicado una restricción que combina las siguientes columnas: `pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid`, pero luego omites la columna `pidboca` en la llave foránea de la tabla `phistorico` al hacer esto: `REFERENCES public.pbombonas (pbid, pserial, pidtama, peid, ppid)`, prueba a ponerlo así: **`REFERENCES public.pbombonas (pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid)`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al crear la tabla `pbombonas` has indicado una restricción que combina las siguientes columnas: `pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid`:

```
... CONSTRAINT bombonas_pk PRIMARY KEY (pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid)
```

Pero luego omites la columna `pidboca` en la llave foránea de la tabla `phistorico` al hacer esto:

```
... REFERENCES public.pbombonas (pbid, pserial, pidtama, peid, ppid)
```

La restricción debería quedar así:

```
ALTER TABLE public.phistorico ADD CONSTRAINT pbombonas_phistorico_fk
FOREIGN KEY                 (pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid)
REFERENCES public.pbombonas (pbid, pserial, pidboca, pidtama, peid, ppid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```